# How to configure interactive web terminal on docker+machine GitLab runners?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-runner

I've added the following configuration to the runner toml config:

```
[session_server]
  listen_address = "[::]:8093" #  listen on all available interfaces on port 8093
  advertise_address = "runner-host-name.tld:8093"
  session_timeout = 1800
```

The manager instance and workers are running in the same VPC on AWS. I have put the manager's private IP address in the `advertise_address` option. This address and port are reachable from worker machines. But when I click on the Debug button in the job, it opened the debug page with the black rectangle and nothing more, no shell appears in it. No errors or warnings related to the session server connectivity in the job log. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What interactive web terminal are you referring to? It almost seems like you're trying to use SSM to access the ec2 instances created by docker+machine?

Comment: I'm referring to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/interactive_web_terminal/